# ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso might be broken or hash wrong

Tags: iso, hash

I downloaded the file ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso three times and i got always the md5-hash f58827df4b80befc7f1e5cf3816d6d36.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes says the md5-hash is 08494b448aa5b1de963731c21344f803.

Is the hash ok and the file on server broken or is the file ok and there is a wrong hash on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes?

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash on the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes agrees with the one on the [Ubuntu Releases page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/MD5SUMS), and an ISO I downloaded from [my campus mirror](ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/os/ubuntu/releases/14.10) has the same hash (`08494b448aa5b1de963731c21344f803`). So I'd say something's wrong with wherever you're downloading it from or your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think my internet connection is ok.
The download of the server-iso-images and 2 other images works fine (hash ok).

I tested the download of an german mirror-image and it works.

I think there is a problem with the file on the original server.

THX

Comment: Can you post the exact link you used to download from the original server?